# ASP.NET 6 get RazorViewEngineOptions from app.ApplicationServices.GetService

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc

How to get `RazorViewEngineOptions` from `app.ApplicationServices.GetService`?

I am using **ASP.NET MVC 6** if that matters at all.

In my 'Startup.cs' I have:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerfactory)
{
    var razorViewEngineOptions = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<????>();
}
```

What I want to know is what service do I need to fetch (shown as `????` in the above code.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want an `IOptions<RazorViewEngineOptions>` type parameter on your `GetService()` call.

Consider the ASP.NET Test Code here:

https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/master/test/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Razor.Test/RazorViewEngineOptionsTest.cs#L39

```
        // Assert
        var accessor = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IOptions<RazorViewEngineOptions>>();
        Assert.Same(fileProvider, accessor.Options.FileProvider);
```

I am not readily able to verify this on my current workstation, and so not sure if this applies to **ASP.NET MVC v6**, I assume it does since this Test is in 'master'.

HTH!